# Telerik ComboBox disable enter click or disable form from being submitted on enter click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-mvc

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC3 application and i am using telerik ComboBox in it. I have a requirement wherein i have to disable the Enter button click in the ComboBox because it is trigerring the form submit method. Below is the code i have

```
Html.Telerik().ComboBox().Name("OpportunityType").Value("-1")
                    .BindTo(new SelectList(Model.OpportunityTypes, "OpportunityID", "OpportunityTypeName"))
                    .ClientEvents(events => events.OnChange("OnOpportunityTypeChange")
                    )
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 180px;" }).Render();
```

i have tried to handle the key press event of the dropdown with as below in document.ready of jquery, but even that didn't solve the purpose. Do we have a keypress event for Telerik ComboBox? my code never reaches there on enter click i tried to alert some value and it didn't show up

```
$("#OpportunityType").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
        return false;
        }
    });
```

any other way to disable the enter key event for this combobox?

Comment: Is the combo box the only element of your form?

Comment: @Rob No. i have few text boxes and check boxes also.

Comment: Have you looked at using the event's preventDefault function?http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: the keypress event itself is not getting fired :( i tried to alert some value on keypress and that never showed up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the handler to the input element - not the hidden one.

i.e.

```
 $("#OpportunityType-input").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
        return false;
        }
    });
```

I hope this helps !

Comment: Well the event is triggered on myside (i put a break point there) when I hit enter ... and I prevent the form from submit.
You can try the same here:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/combobox/clientvalidation

with this selector $("#ProductID-input")

Comment: Thanks for that XMR. My dropdown is similar to the one here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/combobox/clientsideevents. Just try to click enter in the first dropdown. i dont see an event (keypress) in the event log. little confused.

Comment: Are you talking about the DropDownList or the ComboBox in the demo link you shared?

Comment: combobox. it is the first one in the link i shared

Answer (score 0):

According to the first google result for ["telerik combobox stop form submission"](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet/general-discussions/how-to-disable-prevent-enter-key-to-do-pagereload-at-raddatepicker-radcombobox-raddateinput-radtextbox-radnumerictextbox-etc.aspx)

its sounding like you need to attach an event handler for onkeydown and then use both preventDefault and stopPropagation to prevent the postback.

Comment: As already mentioned this is a HTML.Telerik.ComboBox and not a Rad control so the above link doesnt provide answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the

```
<form [...] onkeypress="return validate(event)">
```

to catch the keydown across the form and then use the eventSource property of the passed in eventdetail argument (e) to check for the input field and return false.

Comment: The telerik combo box is not recognizing keypress or keydown client event